# Mocking function imported to many locations

Tags: python, pytest

I want to mock a function in every place it's imported.

### Example

Say I have

```py
# foo.py

def send_email():
    call_email_service()
```

```py
# bar1.py
from foo import send_email

def my_func():
    ...
    send_email()
```

and many other files using `send_email`.  I want a fixture to mock all usages of `send_email`.

### Current best solution

Trying to patch `'foo.send_email'` does not work since you need to patch it the namespace it's used in (namely, I'd have to patch `'bar1.send_email'`).

The best solution I have is rewriting the code like this:

```py
# foo.py

def send_email():
    _send_email_mockable()

def _send_email_mockable():
    call_email_service()
```

and writing a fixture like:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _mock_email_service():
    with patch('foo._send_email_mockable', autospec=True):
        yield
```

That indeed works, but I'd prefer the test logic not to creep into my main logic if possible, and if `send_email` has a complicated function signature, I have to repeat it twice.

Comment: You mock names, not objects. The name under which the value is *use* is what's important, not where the object is defined.

Answer (score 4):

Change your import statements to the following:

```py
# bar1.py

# Previous way
from foo import send_email

# New way
import foo

def my_func():
    ...
    foo.send_email()
```

This will allow the mock to patch `foo` namespace, prior to loading of `send_email` in your destination files.

Comment: Thanks!  That's much cleaner.  It still has a downside though - on a large team, other developers may, in the future, unwittingly just import `send_email`, in which case the mock will not work.  I was really hoping there could be a solution as clean as providing an `everywhere=True` arg to `patch` or something.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, in the case you're describing - given the namespace thingy. To that, I'd defer to more experienced people who may choose to answer here. Until then, this is how I solve this issue in my work.